# Create virtual table with rowid only of another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, virtual-table

Suppose I have a table in sqlite as follows:

```
`name`     `age`
"bob"      20      (rowid=1)
"tom"      30      (rowid=2)      
"alice"    19      (rowid=3)
```

And I want to store the result of the following table using minimal storage space:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name < 'm' ORDER BY age
```

How can I store a virtual table from this resultset that will just give me the ordered resultset. In other words, storing the rowid in an ordered way (in the above it would be `3,1`) without saving all the data into a separate table.

For example, if I stored this information with just the rowid in a sorted order:

```
CREATE TABLE vtable AS 
SELECT rowid from mytable WHERE name < 'm' ORDER BY age;
```

Then I believe every time I would need to query the `vtable` I would have to join it back to the original table using the `rowid`. Is there a way to do this so that the vtable "knows" the content that it has based on the external table (I believe this is referred to as external-content when creating an `fts` index -- https://sqlite.org/fts5.html#external_content_tables).

Comment: `select rowid`  instead of `select *` ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff so if I did an insert as follows: `CREATE TABLE vtable AS 
SELECT rowid from mytable ORDER BY name;`, how would I get the full dataset when I query that table? Wouldn't that require a join on the id every time I do a query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff just updated the question with an example.

Comment: So you want to save an ordered subset of the table in another table?

Comment: @forpas yes basically the results of the query so I can paginate it or go back to it as needed without having to keep rerunning that query.

Comment: I think you're using "virtual table" in a different sense than sqlite uses.

Comment: Perhaps you mean a temporary table?  Temporary tables can be held in memory to make them fast and efficient, but as Shawn points out, they are not the same as a "virtual table".  You may also want to consider just storing the data in a standard memory construct using the host language, especially if it is a small dataset.  Do you really need it to remain as a query-able table?  Will you need to join on it or execute further queries on just that data?  If not, then seriously consider an in-memory dictionary, list, etc.

Comment: @David542  Also, the link you shared is about FTS (Full Text Search) and is out of context from you describe--not relevant.

Comment: @CPerkins I'd like the table to persist though and act more like a "last executed" query -- so that it is still there if, for example, a user comes back a week later and wants to see the results from their last query. So storing it in a temp structure (memory or tmp table) I think wouldn't work here, though I may be wrong.

Comment: From your last comment it is clear that you want a regular table and since you know how to create it I don't see the point of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe this is referred to as external-content when creating an
> fts.

No a virtual table is CREATED using `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ......  USING module_name (module_parameters)`

Virtual tables are tables that can call a module, thus the USING module_name(module_parameters) is mandatory.

For FTS (Full Text Serach) you would have to read the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) but it could be something like

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bible_fts USING FTS3(book, chapter INTEGER, verse INTEGER, content TEXT)
```

**You very likely don't need/want a VIRTUAL table.**

---

```
CREATE TABLE vtable AS SELECT rowid from mytable WHERE name < 'm' ORDER BY age;
```

Would create a normal table IF it didn't already exist that would persist. And if you wanted to use it then it would probably only be of use by joining it with mytable. Effectively it would allow a snapshot, but at a cost, of at least 4k for every snapshot.

I'd suggest a single table for all snapshots that has two columns a snapshot identifier and the rowid of the snapshot. This would probably be far less space consuming.

## Basic Example

Consider :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, /* NOTE not using an alias of the rowid may present issues as the id's can change */
    name TEXT,
    age INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS snapshot (id TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, mytable_map);

INSERT INTO mytable (name,age) VALUES('Mary',21),('George',22);

INSERT INTO snapshot (mytable_map) SELECT id FROM mytable;

SELECT snapshot.id,name,age FROM snapshot JOIN mytable ON mytable.id = snapshot.mytable_map;
```

And the above is run 3 times with a reasonable interval (seconds so as to distinguish the snapshot id (the timestamp)).

Then you would get 3 snapshots (each with a number of rows but the same value in the id column for each snapshot), the first with 2 rows, the 2nd with 4 and the last with 6 (as each run 2 rows are being added to mytable) :-

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks for this answer. It seems I was misunderstanding what a virtual table was in sqlite.